# Definition of Method of Moments

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

In the mathematical literature, I have found two definitions for the Method of Moments so far:

- The first definition concerns a method for estimating the parameters of a population. This method is described, for instance, in Wikipedia:
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics)
- In probability theory, the Method of Moment concerns a result which allows to prove the convergence in distribution of a sequence of random variables. There is another Wikipedia entry for this method:
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(probability_theory)

My question is whether these two meanings are somehow related, or whether "Method of Moment" is indeed used to describe two unrelated methods?

Comment: I think they are related but not identical.  The common part is using a "weak" property to identify distributions: reasoning that distribution 1 is close to distribution 2 because they predict equal or close expectations of polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two 'methods' are related in that they both use moments $E(X^k)$ of
a distribution. Also, roughly speaking,  they both rely on the fact that moments contain
a lot of information about their distribution. But they are not the same thing.

- The method in probability requires all moments to exist.
  And the goal is to prove convergence.
- The method in statistical estimation requires only as many moments as
  there are parameters to estimate.

As is usual when concepts in different fields have similar names
Wikipedia has a [*"disambiguation" page*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments) to warn of the distinction
and link to each of the concepts separately.